# Save <img> to File Share using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net, webmethod

I am trying to somehow save my image generated with `<input type="file" id="file_capture" capture="user" accept="image/*"/>` through vb.net ajax and save the file into a file share folder.

I need image capture so that if the user is on their phone it will screen capture.

I have tried jquery-webcame with no luck and have ended with only HTML Capture working up to the point when I need to save the file.

So far the image src looks something like this `data:image/jpeg;base64,/...`
When I pass the `src` into `ajax` I tried to read it using `Net.WebClient` but I am unsure how to get the address of the img when all I have is the `src` value to use for `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile`

VB.NET

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> Public Shared Function SaveImage(ByVal src As String) As String
  Try
    Dim client As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient
    Dim destination = "\\serverName\FolderShareName\"
    client.DownloadFile(src, destination)
  Catch ex As Exception

  End Try
  Return "Pass"
End Function
```

HTML

```
<label class="cameraButton" style="min-width:150px;">Capture File
  <input type="file" id="file_capture" capture="user" accept="image/*"/>
</label>       
<div id="imageHolder" class="col-sm-12" style="border:1px solid red;text-align:center;min-width:150px;" runat="server"> 
</div>
```

JAVASCIRPT  [I created it this way so multiple images can be uploaded]

```
$('#file_capture').change(function () {
            AddNewImage(this);
        });

        function AddNewImage(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var id = $("#imageHolder > div > img").length
                var fullid = "uploadImage" + id++;
                var DIV = document.createElement("DIV");
                DIV.className = "imgWrap"
                DIV.ID = "imgWrapID" + id++;
                DIV.style.display = "inline-block";
                DIV.style.padding = "10px";

                document.getElementById('imageHolder').appendChild(DIV);
                var img = new Image(200, 200); 
                reader.onload = function (e) {                  
                    img.src = e.target.result;
                    img.id = fullid

                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

                var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                btn.innerHTML = "x";
                btn.className = 'top-right';
                btn.name = DIV.ID
                btn.title = fullid
                btn.onclick = function () {
                    $("#" + this.name).remove();
                    $("#" + this.title).remove();
                    $(this).remove();
                    return false;
                };
                DIV.appendChild(btn);
                DIV.appendChild(img);                  
            }
}
```

`client.DownloadFile(src, destination)` 
clearly won't accept the 64bit src value of the image so I need to somehow convert it to a address.

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: I know I saw that when I posted. I was trying to fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image upload with ajax and asp.net returns html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260868/image-upload-with-ajax-and-asp-net-returns-html)

Comment: @Liam when i pass the image as a FormData into my ajax, it converts to ```[object FormData]``` into my ```SaveImage```. What is the compatible type for FormData to vb.net ajax?

Comment: You need to read the file from the request object, as [detailed in the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40261441/542251)